# Why does gcc/clang not inline even on highest optimization level

Tags: c++, optimization, inline

I am wondering why the function `foobar()` is not inlined by gcc/clang. Even with `-O3` no inlining is performed. I would have expected that gcc is smart enough to do so.
If I add the `inline` keyword to the function, the inlining is performed. However, I thought specifying the `inline` keyword manually is kind of deprecated.

I also tried compiling this example on my local machine with gcc-8 but same results.

```
#include <cstdio>

int foobar()
{   
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", foobar());
}
```

[Compiler Explorer.](https://godbolt.org/z/IdmBhU)

Comment: The call is inlined in the link you provide, there is no call to foobar in main.

Comment: Please, note that the function is there (beside of the inlined call), as it might be linked from another translation unit (even although there is no other TU in this case).

Comment: I think you're confusing function calls with function definitions.

Comment: The original meaning of `inline` has been moved meanwhile. As the compiler can determine self best what's worth to be inlined, it doesn't need hints for that anymore. `inline` is now used to mark duplicated extern definitions (which would cause link errors otherwise) e.g. a variable or function definition in a header (which must be `inline`d). ([`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline))

Comment: @Scheff: Thank you very much. Indeed I overlooked this fact. I just saw that the function is still there but indeed it is never called.

Comment: @MarkusFranke make it into a `static` function.

Comment: @Mat in the fact it was not inlined only optimized out as the result was known compile time as in this example: https://godbolt.org/z/sj9oML The first call was optimized out, second inlined

Answer (score 4):

They inline even without the `inline` keyword. Your example was too trivial and the inling was not needed as the return value was known during the compilation

https://godbolt.org/z/tNcSrf

```
volatile int x;

int foobar(int x)
{   
   return x * x;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", foobar(x));
}

foobar:
        mul     r0, r0, r0
        bx      lr
main:
        push    {r3, lr}
        ldr     r3, .L5
        ldr     r0, .L5+4      //inlined here
        ldr     r1, [r3]
        mul     r1, r1, r1
        bl      printf
        movs    r0, #0
        pop     {r3, pc}
.L5:
        .word   x
        .word   .LC0
.LC0:
        .ascii  "%d\012\000"
```

it leaves the copy of the function as it may be called from another translation unit. If the function is called many times in the same unit compiler is free to do not inline it at all (depending on the compile options).

to make sure that the function will be always inlined you need to use attribute

```
inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int foobar(int x);
```

or

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int foobar(int x);
```

Comment: I saw your global `volatile int x;`. I strongly assume, you did it this way to prevent compile-time computations. Another simple option is to make such variables subject of console input. I.e. `int x; scanf("%d", &x);` should achieve the same effect. (A variable value given at runtime by user input _cannot_ be known/considered at compile time.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff it has to be made used or side effect prone. Method does not matter.